# Reference to button by name

Tags: button, extjs

i am have 2 forms, and in first form i am have button1:

```
   Buttons[{
    width: 350,
    text: 'Book',
    name:'button1'}]
```

on second form i am have button2, and when button click in second form, then button in first form disabled, before i am use id of button (id:'button1') and make this:

```
Ext.getCmp('button1').setDisabled(true);
```

but now i am remove ID and use name in components. But i am didn"t know how disable button1 by name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons don't have a `name` property - you should consult the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/#!/api/Ext.button.Button) to see what configuration variables you have available to you.  I'd instead assign it an `itemId` so you can make use of the `up()` and `down()` functions in order to easily find an item in the component hierarchy from an event handler.

Or if you want to find it directly you can use the following to lookup up the item:

```js
{
    text   : 'Button',
    itemId : 'buttonSelector'
}
```

```js
var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#buttonSelector');
if(button.length) button[0].disable();
```

Keep in mind that the `ComponentQuery` utility returns an array of items (even if you make your `itemId` unique).  Here's a simple [fiddle / demonstration](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/626).

---

In response to your comment, there may be confusion in regards to what the `buttons` config actually does - according to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-buttons) it is shorthand for the following:

```js
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    ui: 'footer',
    defaults: {minWidth: minButtonWidth},
    items: [
        { xtype: 'component', flex: 1 },
        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
    ]
}]
```

... this creates an extra *"step"* in the hierarchy which you must account for in a query.  For example, if your form had an `itemId` of ***formId*** you could try something like:

```js
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#formId toolbar #myButtonId')[0].disable();
```

I've [updated your fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/63l) to demonstrate this.

Comment: if this buttons is in different forms that is not work(

Comment: Component queries can be used to catch many components or isolate particular ones.  I think you need to be more specific about your requirements - can you set up a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?